# Fix div at top and bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to finish a page using bootstrap, but i'm stuck in a simple thing (unfortunately)

Well, I have this code here - http://jsfiddle.net/tofanelli/1npw7x62/2/ - and I want to make the H3 always be on top, and the pink area always goes to bottom, but still "inside" of green area, regardless how many content is in the page.

So far, when I have just 2 or 3 text lines, all the content stay on the middle of the page in mobile view. How to avoid this and make the title stays on top and pink area on bottom?

You may say "just use position 'fixed' or 'absolute' or 'sticky'... I already tried all these options, but none of them really worked as I want to.

Cheers =)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 blue nopad" style="height:100vh;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6 green">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h3>h3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor. Sed iaculis posuere diam ut cursus. <em>Morbi commodo sodales nisi id sodales. Proin consectetur, nisi id commodo imperdiet, metus nunc consequat lectus, id bibendum diam velit et dui.</em> Proin massa magna, vulputate nec bibendum nec, posuere nec lacus. <small>Aliquam mi erat, aliquam vel luctus eu, pharetra quis elit. Nulla euismod ultrices massa, et feugiat ipsum consequat eu.</small></p></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 pink"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



.blue{
    background: blue;
}

.green {
    background: green;
    height: 100vh;
}
.pink {
    background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/JTBennett/1npw7x62/4/

```
position: fixed; top:0; <!---for sticking to the top of the window --->
position: absolute; bottom:0; <!---for sticking to the bottom of a div --->
```

Check this link for a writeup on the properties of each position value: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

-Joel

[I took some liberty and center aligned the content of the two divs in question - apologies if that's not what you want.

Also, if you scroll down you will see that the header div goes under the footer div - to fix this, add "z-index:9999;" to your header properties.]

Comment: Hey joel... thanks for helping me, but this code is not really working as intended... it broke whole layout of page... is it the same code you posted?

http://imgur.com/5iUqF5f

Comment: The result you have there is due to the width settings I put on the divs because I wasn't aware you'd be having a sidebar.

They are set at 100vw - change this to a percentage or fixed size that reflects your layout. You can also try erasing the width specifications entirely.

Otherwise, you can post the entire site code on jsfiddle and I can find the definite cause.

Comment: the pink area is 100vw because i need it to fill the whole width in its space on green area... that's why.... and the green and blue area needs to be 50/50 for my purposes.... but i will try to give a shot after you send me this code.... thanks very much =D

Comment: Send me a link back to the jsfiddle that is malfunctioning maybe - the one I sent works perfectly fine. Here it is with the z-index fix:

https://jsfiddle.net/JTBennett/1npw7x62/7/


Did you change anything on yours?

Comment: this version you just sent me broke the whole layout.... the pink area is bigger than the green area..... check it out.... something right is running wrong =D

Comment: What browser are you using? It works fine for me in Safari and Chrome. If we're looking at the same jsfiddle and you haven't modified it in any way (including adding it into another page, etc) then there must be a browser compatibility issue here.

If you prefer to communicate live about this, I'd be willing to do that. https://hangouts.google.com  ->  my email address is me@joeltbennett.com if you want to send a message, I'm on now.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/1npw7x62/5/

```
.green {
    background: green;
    height: 100vh;
}
.pink {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: pink;
}
```

Comment: hey.... it almost works.... it seems the "pink" area is floating over the green area and do not resize when needed.... mind to take a look?